# Unable to run cqlsh; Timed out creating connection

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I am unable to run cqlsh:

```
$ cqlsh  10.230.34.16 9160
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'10.230.34.16': OperationTimedOut('errors=Timed out creating connection, last_host=None',)})
```

The rpc service listening on 9160, but still cqlsh is unable to connect to it?

```
$ netstat -an |grep 9160| grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 10.230.34.16:9160     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Any ideas what I can check?

Am using datastax cassandra 2.1.0

Comment: Cqlsh in 2.1.0 doesn't use Thrift (9160) anymore, make sure port 9042 is available.

Comment: I have start_native_transport as false, is there a reason it is false by default?

Comment: it works after enabling start_native_transport

Comment: In my case, the default `connect-timeout` value of `5` wasn't enough. Adding the flags `--connect-timeout 3600 --debug` solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. check the cassandra.yaml file on the line with rpc_port : normally by default = 9160
2. login to the machine hosting cassandra
3. try cqlsh 127.0.0.1 9160 : should be ok in any case
4. try cqlsh [IP of host] 9160 : if ok then cassandra reachable from lan, if ko then cassandra is not reachable from lan but only localhost 127.0.0.1

Comment: Under my experience the 4 point is the one which solve this type of problems in most of the situations

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit old, but in case anybody got into this issue.

Base on this [QNA](http://qnalist.com/questions/5162594/cassandra-2-1-0-unable-to-use-cqlsh), it seems the driver and the protocol has change.
Try

> cqlsh 127.0.0.1 9042

It solved the issue for me.